# callback in nested function

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, callback

i have a function which calls the another function and so on.

```
function A(args,callback){    
// make ajax request
//  on response 
    B()    
}

function B(args){

// make ajax request
//  on response 
    C()
}

function C(args){

  // make ajax request
  //  on response 
    D()
}
```

I am making such ten ajax calls. Two questions...

1. can anyone explain me what is callback-hell? Is this a callback Hell?
2. If i call callback() inside function D, will it get called. I am not passing callback as argument to my other functions.

Comment: I would think really hard before doing 10 ajax calls in a row that all depended on each other, if that's what you're saying.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a well-established definition for "callback hell", but I *would* call many deeply-nested callbacks "callback spaghetti".

Comment: @apsillers. LOL, my thoughts exactly, BTW I've found the definition to that phrase, look below.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't know what **you**'re calling *callback hell* but it's one hell of a **spaghetti code**.

> **What is "callback hell"?**
>   Asynchronous javascript, or javascript that uses callbacks, is hard to get right intuitively.

[Source](http://callbackhell.com/)

2.No, `callback` is not defined inside `D` so you will get an Error.

Comment: Lets take if i pass my callback reference from A to B and C then receive it in D... will i able to achieve.

Comment: @theJava, Yes, in that case it will be valid, probably spaghetti but valid. I've never seen a good reason for doing 10 async operations one after the other. usually when those kind of things are being done, it's a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `D()` there is no way to call `callback` because it is not defined there. What I mean by this is as long as you don't pass `arguments` down the callbacks then you are not having your `callback` variable inside `D()`. Callback hell is a situation where callbacks call each-other meaning `A()` calls `B()` and `B()` calls `A()`.

Comment: Imho you don't need (endless) "recursion" for a callback hell.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, but callbacks are not that hard to debug, but the real hell is when callbacks are constantly calling each-other, because then debugging results in a different output than what you would get if you do not breakpoint inside the callbacks :)

Comment: If i pass my callback reference via A to B and B to C an then C to D... will that result in callback hell

Comment: @theJava This begs to the question is dynamic programming a callback hell? In your case I would not call it a callback hell.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass function reference as a parameter in JavaScript and use this reference to call related function whenever/ wherever we want.

for more info see this link http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/